# coldfusion jrpp threadID, do higher numbers mean anything?

Tags: java, multithreading, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, connection-timeout

I don't know much about threads in CF. I am trying to troubleshoot an issue in CF9, Windows Server 2008.  Page requests start to timeout so we will restart the server.  I've been looking at the logs and noticed that the threadID will be between 1000-1250 during the trouble. After the CF service is restarted, the threadID is under 100.

Does the fact that the threadID is high mean anything?

Comment: don't take this as gospel, but generally when I've been working on thread dumps from CF, the thread ID's have never been as high as 1000, so I'd treat that as suspicious. Have you run any thread dumps whilst the application is in trouble? You can use JVisualVM, JConsole or SendSignal.exe. run 5 dumps, 10 seconds apart, then open the log file in Samurai and note the number of jrpp threads and look at what they're up to

Comment: I haven't done any thread dumps and I was hoping to not have to go that deep into it. I just noticed the trend and was curious what it meant, if anything.